# What is this 50's or 60's "alien invasion" movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

Saw this movie in the mid 70's on TV after school one afternoon.

I remember a few scenes, but not who starred in it. I was thinking Chuck Connors but I couldn't find it on his list of movies.

The first scene I remember is where a blob-like alien creatures with long necks (no legs... the body was on the ground and the long neck ended with a  90° bend with (maybe) an eye on the end of the neck stem) which had invaded a small town.

This scene was at a ranch at night & the rancher went out to see what was disturbing his livestock. When he looked towards the barn, he saw these creatures on the roof dropping off on top of his cattle (or horses) which were in a pen...

The next scene was in a building where a man (& woman?) were hiding in an office with a door that had a frosted glass window. One of the creatures came down the hall & busted the glass with its long neck trying to get in.

Sorry I couldn't think of more, but I've had this one on my mind for decades now & haven't discovered the name.

Comment: This feels like *War of the Worlds* (1953) but only just.

Comment: Was this a US or UK movie..or some other country. I have a possible answer...in fact two...or three.

Comment: How big were the aliens. Soccer ball size, child-size, man-size?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222141/movie-from-70s-or-earlier-about-a-genetically-created-organism-that-almost-took (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 9):

"Island of Terror"(1966)?

They weren't aliens but the creatures looked alien. They were created by a scientist and they were legless and had a protruding tentacle, below is a clip featuring one of the creatures.

There is a scene where the creatures, called 'silicates', feed on some cattle that have been injected with something which is deadly to these creatures, so that they can be killed.

Comment: That was one of my guesses.

Comment: And [here](https://youtu.be/w7jghT4P--k?t=1h17m12s)'s the scene where the creatures drop off the roof on top of the cows in the pen.